# Bootstrap <button> links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap uses `button` as links. How can I create an href or link this to something?

I am trying to swap these for `a` but, as expected, they get all messed up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter button](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) :

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Large button</button>
```

If you want to add a link then simply add a class to that a href :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it simple you can add class `btn` to link like this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" >ddd</a>
```